# Code Generation Templates of Migration Classes in FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, fluent-migrator

Are there any code generation templates available for use with FluentMigrator to generate migration classes from SQL (T-SQL) statements?

Ideally I would like to take text that contains statements for creating tables, indexes, etc and generate a migration class with the Up and Down methods containing the equivalent of the original SQL statements.

I'm only concerned with solutions based on open source or free code generation tools.

Comment: Do you mean generating migrations that use Execute.Sql or Execute.Script to call your sql scripts? Or do you mean a generator that converts sql into FluentMigrator's fluent syntax?

Comment: A generator that converts sql statements into FM's syntax. Let's say you already have some tool or process that generates the sql statements and you then want to be able to create fluent migrations from them.

Comment: Sorry, nothing like that exists as far as I know. It sounds really difficult parsing sql into c# code. Have you checked the google user group?

Comment: I did a pretty thorough search. I assume nothing exists as well, but it never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote an application that will read an existing database and then generate a FluentMigrator Migration Class with both Up and Down methods.

http://pfsolutions-mi.com/Product/FluentMigratorClassGenerator

Comment: Any chance you can submit this as a pull request to FluentMigrator. We can add it to the Contrib section. Thanks.

Comment: That is something I will have to think about.

Comment: MigrationNo does not work in the code. The database setting value never gets updated by the UI, it is always 1 (editing that in the SDF file manually will work). However everything else seems to work. Needs some refinements but functions in my short tests.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing like this exists as far as I know. The closest thing is the ability to write your own schema dump code. That could be used to take an existing database and generate FluentMigrator syntax from it. [Here](http://computeristsolutions.com/blog/posts/2011/4/dumping-existing-schema-with-fluentmigrator) is a sample of how one might do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Guru Kathiresan's [T4 Template for creating FM initial schemas](http://twinforms.com/fm.zip).  This link came from the [FluentMigrator Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fluentmigrator-google-group/Zm0ubgSKTJs).